# SQL Server Profiler How to see the actual parameter values of inner sql commands?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

While using Microsoft SQL Profiler with `SP:SmtpStarting` event checked, I can see the SQL commands executed by a specific stored procedure.

I can see commands like:

```
SELECT MyUsers FROM SomeTable WHERE UserName = @UserName
```

which includes the parameter names and not the values of them.

How can I catch the command together with the actual values like:

```
SELECT MyUsers FROM SomeTable WHERE UserName = 'Joe Due'
```

I need this for debugging some internal stored procedures separated from the main stored procedure.

Comment: You **cannot** - since this is ***NOT*** what happens! The parameters are ***NOT*** inlined to replace the placeholders - instead, SQL Server gets the query, with placeholders, a list of placeholders, and their values.

Comment: What is the `SP:SmtpStarting` event?  I expected to see it in the "Stored Procedures" events within SQL Server Profiler, but it's not there (SQL 2008 R2).

Comment: So what is the fast way to debug it without fill the parameters manually?